# what's the difference between exporting a component and importing its module in another module?

Tags: angular, typescript

when working in Angular, let's say we have *module A* and *module B*, if I want to use "*A-component*" inside components of *module B*, then what's the difference between importing *module A* inside *Module B*
, and adding the "*A-component*" in the exports of *module A* ?

I tried both, and I think they are not the same thing, this is confusing.

Comment: if you want to use A-component directly in  module B you have to export it and import the exporting module. *

I think im missing some part of your question

Comment: A component can only "declared" in one (and only in one) Module. This is the reason that components that we want use in severals modules (generally utils components) should be declared and exported in one module that is imported by the others modules

Answer (score 0):

You need to export and import, not just one.

Unless you use default exports, your code would need to look something like this:

a.mjs

```js
export class myClass {
  ...
}
```

b.mjs

```js
import { myClass as myClassFromA } from './a.mjs'
```

or with default exports:

a.mjs

```js
export default class myClass {
  ...
}
```

b.mjs

```js
import myClassFromA from './a.mjs'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. importing module A inside Module B
   It means that you would like to access **inside Module B** components, pipes, directives and sevices **from module A**
2. adding the "A-component" in the exports of module
   It means that you are making this component accessible for those who is using module A

Answer (score 0):

Angular based on [Dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection). For example, you want to use A-component from B-module, you **NEED** to export A-component from A-module and import A-module in B-module.

What if you directly use A-component without exporting?

Then, **you have to provide all dependencies of A-component in B-module**, so it's a bad practice. It's better to export it from module.